# Hide console Authorization Logs in Blazor Webassembly

Tags: blazor, blazor-webassembly

How can we hide the logs that are written to the console, especially the Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization ones?
I have thought that setting Microsoft Log to None would solve the issue.
The appsettings.json file for Blazor Webassembly

```
  "Logging": {
    "IncludeScopes": false,
    "LogLevel": {
      "MinimumLevel": {
        "Default": "None",
        "System": "None",
        "Microsoft": "None"

      }
    }
  }
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: see: [Configure logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-6.0#configure-logging)

Comment: @Luuk, I have followed the documentation and I have tried  "LogLevel": none but it is still showing all the logs.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can disable this logger using logger filter rule:

```cs
builder.Logging.AddFilter("Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.*", LogLevel.None);
```

or

```cs
builder.Services.PostConfigure<LoggerFilterOptions>(opt => 
    opt.Rules.Add(
        new LoggerFilterRule(null, "Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.*", LogLevel.None, null)
        ));
```

`LoggerFilterOptions` is registered in `LoggingServiceCollectionExtensions.AddLogging`. `LoggerFactory` uses these options and handles any changes to the filter rules.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, all I had to do was to wire the Logger in Program.cs.

```
    using using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

[...]
        builder.Logging.SetMinimumLevel(LogLevel.None);
```